# What is Materializer used for in Akka Http SingleRequest and Unmarshaling?

Tags: akka-http

Generally the materializer is used to create Actors for the stream, and all the Akka Http documentation says one is required to make requests.

However,

1. Seems like Http().singleRequest() doesn't require one. It seems to use the systemMaterializer
2. The only
   place that requires it is the Unmarshal.to method, which uses it
   only as a backup in case there is no implicit execution context
   provided (it gets a backup execution context from the materializer)

So this leads to two questions

1. It is silly to create a materialized that will never be used just for the Unmarshal.to call. Is there a way around it? (Aside from creating my  own Unmarshal)
2. How can I get singleRequest to use a custom executionContext/thread-pool?